# Is a ball always connected in a connected metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If I have a connected metric space $X$, is any ball around a point $x\in X$ also connected?

Answer (score 27):

It is easy to see the answer is no. Take the unit circle in the plane, with the metric inherited from the Euclidian metric in the plane. Then remove the "top" point (coordinates $(0,1)$). Then a "ball" (small disk) around a point close to "the top", restricted to the "circle with the top removed," will be disconnected. Here the metric space is the circle **with the top point removed**.

Comment: Can you explain how a ball would be disconnected there?

Comment: It would contain a bit of the circle to the left of the top point and a bit of the circle to the right.

Comment: Concretely: The open ball of radius $2$ around $(1,0)$ consists of the circle minus $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: @Slade - that is not a very good example, because the center of the ball you chose is ... not in the metric space to begin with. But take a "ball" of radius 1 centered somewhere close to the top.

Comment: @mathguy: Is $(1, 0)$ not in the space? It's on the unit circle, and it's not the removed point (that's $(0, 1)$).

Comment: Oh yes, it is, my bad.

Comment: So essentially a horseshoe. (Not Smale's.)

Comment: What I don't get here is why is the metric space connected in this example? If the ball around a point close to the top is restricted to the metric space then wouldn't it also just be missing the coordinate (0,1). If that ball is disconnected then why is the original metric space without (0,1) connected?

Comment: @FatFeynman - obviously the answer is correct, otherwise it wouldn't have 26 upvotes and 0 downvotes. The original space is connected because it is connected, that has nothing to do with what happens when you restrict to a small ball. The original space is connected because you can go from one side of the top point to the other side by traversing the entire unit circle; you can't do that when you restrict to a small ball around a point close to the top.

Comment: What if you add the requirement that $X$ is a connected metric space and find $B(x,r) \subset X$ such that $B(x,r)$ is not connected? Also, I am aware the answer is correct but I am trying to understand why.

Comment: @FatFeynman - what you are asking is exactly the same as the original question. Consider the Euclidean plane. X is the unit circle (defined by $x^2 + y^2 = 1$) with the top (the point $(0,1)$) removed. Your center "$x$" is some point **on $X$** close to the top, and $r$ is chosen so that the ball $B(x,r)$ (in the metric space $X$, not in the Euclidean plane!) is disconnected.

Comment: Then I still fail to see why you wouldn't be able to go around the point $(0,1)$ by going around the boundary of the ball $B(x,r)$

Answer (score 19):

No. The [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) is a connected subspace of the plane that becomes totally disconnected when a certain point is removed, so open balls centred at the other points cannot be connected if they are small enough to exclude the explosion point.

Comment: Pretty big gun to shoot a fly, eh?

Comment: @mathguy: Not really: it shows that in this case, at least, even changing to some equivalent metric won’t help. And it’s a very standard example.

Comment: We may have different views on the purpose of posting answers here. I doubt that someone who can't solve the original question on their own can within a short time understand the fine points of the Kuratowski fan, or learn much from it.

Comment: @mathguy: I suspect that you’ve not been around very long, as otherwise you’d very likely know that in general I favor answers that match the probable level of the querent. In this case, however, (a) it’s not clear to me that the question wasn’t asked simply for information (i.e., a yes or no answer), (b) the K-K fan example has desirable extra properties and occurred to me immediately, and (c) though I usually concentrate on the original querent, it is in fact desirable to have answers suited to a range of potential readers.

Comment: An example of the last point: I (not the OP) appreciate this answer.

Comment: I actually really like answers like this, because inevitably someone will see a question like this one answered simply, and they'll ask "Okay, but every ball _contains_ a connected ball, right?" or "But if a space is connected and I delete a point, then there's a connected ball somewhere, right?"  Referring to a standard "big" counterexample is pretty nice (though I agree it's not always optimal from the point of the asker, and we should have answers like mathguy's as well).

Comment: @mathguy: I too find this answer useful even though I haven't made the effort to figure out for myself why the K-K fan has the claimed property.

Comment: Genius! +1 you are the best dr scott

Answer (score 8):

There are even *complete path-connected* metric spaces that contain a point $x$ such that *no* ball around $x$ is connected, for example

$$ \{\langle x,0\rangle \mid x\ge 1\} \cup
\{\langle 1,y\rangle \mid 0\le y\le 1 \} \cup
\{\langle x,\tfrac1x \rangle \mid x\ge 1 \} \cup
\bigcup_{n=3}^\infty \{ \langle x,\tfrac1n \rangle \mid 2 \le x \le n \}
 $$

No ball of finite radius around $\langle 2,0\rangle$ is connected.

---

And here's a sketch of a complete and connected (but not path-connected) subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ where *no ball whatsoever, around any point,* is connected:

[image: computer-generated sketch]

Each of the gaps in the Cantor set on the left will eventually be contracted -- but the smaller the gap, the farther to the right will this happen.

Comment: Woah.... that last counterexample is a psychedelic mixture of mind-boggling and cool.

Answer (score 7):

Just take a plane without a segment, and consider a small ball near the center of the segment. There's no need to get complicated stuff.

Answer (score 1):

On the positive side, if $(X,d)$ is a [length metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) then every open ball $B(a, r)\subset (X,d)$ is path connected. (Every closed ball is connected as well, since, in this situation, each closed ball is either a singleton or is the closure of an open ball and the closure of a connected subset in a metric space is connected.)

Edit. The proof is utterly straightforward: Let $B(a,R)$ be an open ball centered at $a$ of radius $R$. For each point $x\in B(a,R)$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a path $p_{ax}$ (connecting $a$ to $x$ of length $< d(x,a)+\epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon:= R- d(a,x)$, we obtain that this path is entirely contained in the open ball $B(a,R)$. Hence, $B(a,R)$ is path connected.

Comment: Proof? This is a nice contrast to Henning's counterexample, by the way.

Comment: @goblin: See the edit.