# Does there exist a connected metric space $X$ all of whose nonempty open subsets $U\neq X$ are not connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Question is the title. Is there an infinite connected metric space $X$ such that if $U\subseteq X$ is nonempty, open, and isn't all of $X$, then $U$ is not connected?

I've tried to prove that no such space can exist using the uniqueness of dispersion points/explosion points, but haven't had much luck.

Rephrasing the question: Must every infinite connected metric space contain a nontrivial (not empty or the space itself) connected open subset?

EDIT: in light of Alessandro Codenotti's comment showing that such space does exist, let me up the ante somewhat. Is there a connected metric space that that has no infinite subspace with the above property? That is, given an infinite metric space $(X,d)$ can I always find a connected subspace $Y\subseteq X$ that contains a nontrivial connected open subset with respect to itself?

Comment: Given $x\in X$, shouldn't the connected component of $x$ in $N = \{y\in X\colon d(x,y)<\delta\}$ provide an example when $\delta$ is small enough that $N\ne X$?

Comment: @GregMartin What does that provide an example of?

Comment: There may not be such a $\delta>0$, though (I’m thinking of the topologist’s sine curve, the vertical bar specifically).

Comment: In any event, the topologist's sine curve has plenty of open connected subsets.

Comment: @RobertThingum a nontrivial connected open subset of the infinite connected metric space, as per your final paragraph

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1760957/136041 look at the picture here

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti that image seems to be a counterexample, thank you.

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti I'm not entirely convinced that it works for unbounded open subsets. This space minus any point seems still connected to me. Also, the part strictly below the central line seems also connected. But I could be mistaken.

Comment: @QuinnLesquimau that's a good point, having a basis of disconnected sets is not enough (in fact a simpler example of a connected metric space with a basis of disconnected balls is a solenoid). I now suspect that there are no counterexamples to the original question, but I can only see that this is the case for compact metric spaces

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti How would you prove that no such compact such space exists?

Comment: @RobertThingum For a topological space $X$ say that $x\in X$ is a cut point if $X-\{x\}$ is disconnected. A classical theorem of continuum theory (see for example Theorem 6.6 in Nadler's *Continuum Theory*) says that all continua (compact connected metrizable spaces) have at least two non-cut points

Comment: Ohhh, good to know.